# Fully specialised templates and dllexport

Tags: c++, windows, dll, templates

Microsoft says: “Templates cannot be used with functions declared with __declspec (dllimport) or __declspec (dllexport).” ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y86hzch.aspx)).

What does this mean? Can I export a function which has a fully specialized template class reference as an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a `dllexport`/`dllimport`-specific problem, its a general issue with templates - only one compiler currently implements the means to `export` templates, see [Comeaus template FAQ](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#export) for details.

Fully specialized templates however are distinct and concrete types and basically usable with the `__declspec` extension, but there are [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twa2aw10%28VS.80%29.aspx) besides the entry you linked.

Personally i'd mainly avoid templates in the interface here and only use them internally - i don't see the what big benefits the time invested in working around the limitations give you.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you can't `dllexport` a **function template** taking a `std::basic_string<T>&`, but you can of course `dllexport` a **function** taking a `std::string&`.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twa2aw10(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Good example. std::string is rarely seen as a fully specialized template.