# Template, statics and dll

Tags: c++, templates, static, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I am trying to export a function template with a static variable in the definition.

.dll/Foo.h:

```
#ifdef _DLL
#define API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

class API Foo
{
  public:
  template<typename T>
  static T& Get()
  {
    static T _instance;
    return _instance;
  }

  static void Set();
}
```

I want the calls made by the .dll and .exe to refer to the same "_instance" object. I know I can do that by defining the static variable in the .cpp. But in this case i am dealing with templates so i am kind of stuck.

Edit:
Example of what is happening..

.dll/Foo.cpp:

```
void Foo::Set()
{
   Foo::Get<int>() = 10;
}
```

.exe/main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
  auto & x = Foo::Get<int>();
  x = 3;
  std::cout << x; // 3
  Foo::Set();
  std::cout << x; // 3 (I want it to be 10)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fully specialised templates and dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276901/fully-specialised-templates-and-dllexport)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have no issues with exporting the above function. My problem is i want to share the static variable defined within the function (in this case "static T _instance") between my .dll and .exe projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need **separate mark** every template with `API` (`__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)`) and not inline it in class code.

Foo.h file is:

```
#ifdef _DLL
#define API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

class API Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T> 
    API static T& Get();

    static void Set();
};
```

note that we separate mark `Get()` with `API` despite all `Foo` class also marked with `API` (class mark have no effect on template function by fact, so need it mark separate). and no implementation of `Get` here - exported functions anyway can not be inline.

so dll code (Foo.cpp) must look like:

```
#include "foo.h"

template<typename T>    
API T& Foo::Get()
{
    __pragma(message("__imp_" __FUNCDNAME__)) // for debug
    static T _instance;
    return _instance;
}

void Foo::Set()
{
    Foo::Get<int>() = 10;
}
```

note we again explicitly use `API` (`__declspec(dllexport)`) in implementation of function body. this is critical important - compiler not warning you, if you skip `API` here, but without this - `Get` will be not exported.

for sure that at this point all correct - copy string produced by `__pragma(message("__imp_" __FUNCDNAME__))` *(it will be look like `__imp_??$Get@H@Foo@@SAAEAHXZ`)* and search **exactly** (symbol to symbol) this string in created *.lib* file - after you build dll. if it exist - all ok, otherwise no sense continue (with exe)

and in exe :

```
#include "../foo_dll/foo.h"

Foo::Get<int>() = 3;
Foo::Set();
if (Foo::Get<int>() != 10)
{
    __debugbreak();
}
```